# how to make console automatically zoom to full screen when running (In C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I want to make a game by coding on Visual Studio. When I run code, the console will appear but it's small. And I need to press maximize to make it full screen.

After I google about window.h, I use this code:

```
void ConsoleSize(SHORT width, SHORT height)
{
    HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    SMALL_RECT WindowSize;
    WindowSize.Top = 0;
    WindowSize.Left = 0;
    WindowSize.Right = width;
    WindowSize.Bottom = height;

    SetConsoleWindowInfo(hStdout, 1, &WindowSize);
}
```

But it only makes the console bigger, not automatically full screen.
So please help me.
Thanks.
I'm not good at English so my question will have some grammatical errors. Sometimes it doesn't do what I want but I sincerely thank you all.

Comment: SetConsoleDisplayMode

Comment: but when I use SetConsoleDisplayMode, it'll not have a Title Bar. Do you have another way?

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted: full screen with no title bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written two functions, `maxsc()` and `fullsc()` are two different full screen, you could use these two functions separately to see if it can meet your needs.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
using namespace std;
void maxsc()
{
    HWND Hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    ShowWindow(Hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE);
}
void fullsc()
{
    HWND Hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    int x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    int y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    LONG winstyle = GetWindowLong(Hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
    SetWindowLong(Hwnd, GWL_STYLE, (winstyle | WS_POPUP | WS_MAXIMIZE) & ~WS_CAPTION & ~WS_THICKFRAME & ~WS_BORDER);
    SetWindowPos(Hwnd,HWND_TOP,0,0,x,y,0);

}
int main()
{
    //maxsc();
    fullsc();
    return 0;
}
```